# Why is this function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to convert a string to integer. I know that there are built-in functions to do it, but still i want to know why is this function not working:
**JS:** - saved as `js1.js`

```
function atoi(str)
 {
  l = str.length;
  s2 = "0"
  for(i=0;i<l;i++)
   {
    if(str.charAt(i) != '1' || str.charAt(i) != '2' || str.charAt(i) != '3' || str.charAt(i) != '4' || str.charAt(i) != '5' || str.charAt(i) != '6' || str.charAt(i) != '7' || str.charAt(i) != '8' || str.charAt(i) != '9' || str.charAt(i) != '0')
     {
        break;
     }
     s2 = s2.concat(str.charAt(i));
   }
  return Number(s2); 
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="js1.js">
  </script>
  <Script>
    function printnum()
     {
      n = atoi(document.getElementById('numtxt').value)
      document.write(n);
     }
  </script>
  <title>
    Test JS1 functions
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="numtxt">
  <input type="button" onclick="printnum()">
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank You.

Comment: You should read about [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to understand boolean operations a bit better.

Comment: `function atoi(n){return ~~n;}`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in that for loop is all absurd and difficult to understand what exactly you want. please state clear requirements and what have you tried for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You give up and `break` if the first character is not a `1` **or** if it is not a `2`, etc.

If it is `1` then it isn't `2` and you `break`.

You want to be using `&&` not `||`.

Answer (score 1):

this or-thing you have there is always true, like:

```
If a!=3||a!=4
```

any value a can have, this is always true, so is with more terms

Comment: Thank u i got it fixed with '&'

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use && instead of ||

```
if(str.charAt(i) != '1' && str.charAt(i) != '2' && 
str.charAt(i) != '3' && str.charAt(i) != '4' &&
str.charAt(i) != '5' && str.charAt(i) != '6' &&
str.charAt(i) != '7' && str.charAt(i) != '8' &&
str.charAt(i) != '9' && str.charAt(i) != '0')
```